# Efficient algorithm to compare arrays problem

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays, space-complexity, efficiency

I was submitted an interesting problem, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Define a function `p(x, y)` that takes int x and y, with `y > x` and returns an int.

`p(x, y) = x & (x+1) & (x+2) & ... & (y-1) & y`

There are then two arrays X of length N and Y of length M representing x and y, in binary with `M >= N > 0`. X and Y are consistently indexed, so that `X[0]` and `Y[0]` represent the least significant digit of x and y.

The final goal is to write an efficient algorithm that computer `p(x, y)`. The ideal solution would be to have a time complexity of *O(M)* and a space complexity of *O(M)*. 
We can assume that the bitwise AND operator is already implemented with a complexity of *O(M)* in both time and space. There's also no need to work on the binary representation of the numbers. Pseudocode is fine.

Comment: Please credit the original source where you encountered this task.

Comment: `wasn't able to find a solution` Please show where your efforts got you.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $x$ and $y$ in binary as
\begin{align}
x&=x_{M-1} \ldots x_0 \\
y&=y_{M-1} \ldots y_0
\end{align}
(This is exactly the contents of your arrays.)
Since $x \neq y$, there must be a first bit (from the left) at which they differ. Say that this bit is $x_i \neq y_i$. Since $y > x$, we know that $y_i = 1$ and $x_i = 0$. Thus
\begin{align}
x &= x_{M-1} \ldots x_{i+1} 0 x_{i-1} \ldots x_0 \\
y &= x_{M-1} \ldots x_{i+1} 1 y_{i-1} \ldots y_0
\end{align}
The following two integers are in the range $x,\ldots,y$:
\begin{align}
&x_{M-1} \ldots x_{i+1} 0 1 \ldots 1 \\
&x_{M-1} \ldots x_{i+1} 1 0 \ldots 0
\end{align}
This shows that if you take the AND of all integers from $x$ to $y$, you get
$$
x_{M-1} \ldots x_{i+1} 0 0 \ldots 0
$$